# Android: PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR customization

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, porter-duff

While drawing on Canvas using PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR, a black trail is left after move event. Can this be customized, for instance, I want to change trail's width and color?